# c# TextBox problems, cannot get the arguments

Tags: c#

Something seems to be fishy about this code and I am not sure how to resolve it.

Basically player.Name should get the arguments from the TextBox changed and insert into it, but it seems that it doesnt do anything like that... Or maybe Im checking it the wrong way...

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Player player = new Player();
            player.Name = textBox1.Text; //Problematic line
        }

        private void Button_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Player player = new Player();

            switch (player.Name.ToUpper())
            {
                case "N/A": Label_Question.Text = "Please set your name!"; break;
                default: Label_Question.Hide(); goto QuizStart;
            }
            QuizStart:
            {

            }

        }
```

Comment: You're creating new instances of `Player` each time then it will always have default value. Make it a private class member. I don't mention that useless `goto` or that `switch`/`case` which is simply an `if` (BTW do string comparison using `String.Equals()`).

Comment: The problem is you do not make your `Player` instance to a class scope, but method/event scope. Also, ***DON'T USE GOTO!!!!***

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti just post is as answer ...

Comment: You also probably dont need a new player every time the user presses a key

Comment: I have class Player. I have everything defined as it should, dont mind the goto Im just using it for the test purposes

Comment: @TomislavTomiNikolic do as Adriano said and it wil work :D

Comment: @FeDe just few lines and I don't think this question will help anyone else in future...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti that is true. still think a written example will help him :P

Comment: @TomislavTomiNikolic You might have your class, but you create a new instance of it at the start of all methods. Create a field or member property inside your form so you can set the changes on a single instance, instead of on a new instance of your Player class each time

Comment: First I want to question the whole `TextChanged`-Method. You actually don't even need it. Just ensure a PlayerName is set, when the Start Button is clicked. You can access `textbox1.Text` inside the ClickMethod. Just check if a Player has set his name and Continue. Otherwise every single character typed into that textbox will trigger the event ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest *extracting a method* instead of cramming everything into single `Button_Start_Click`:

```
  private Boolean IsPlayerValid(Player player) {
    if (null == player)
      return false;

    if (String.Equals("N/A", player.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {  
      Label_Question.Text = "Please set your name!";

      return false;
    }

    //TODO: you may want add up conditions here

    return true;
  }

  private void Button_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Player player = new Player() {
      player.Name = textBox1.Text // you may want this - assign a player's Name
    };

    if (!IsPlayerValid(player))
      return;

    Label_Question.Hide(); 

    // Quiz Start
  }
```

Comment: There is just a small problem, it crashes and im getting this error
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Quiz.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're creating a new instance of "Player" on both the textchanged and the button press events, which means that the player in the button press is Always empty.

Something like this should fix things for you:

```
Player player;

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        player = new Player();
        player.Name = textBox1.Text; //Problematic line
    }

    private void Button_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (player.Name.ToUpper())
        {
            case "N/A": 
               Label_Question.Text = "Please set your name!"; 
               return;
            default: 
               Label_Question.Hide(); 
               break;
        }
    }
```

Or why not skip the textchanged all together (unless you want to do something else in the code that isn't shown here):

```
Player player;

    private void Button_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        player = new Player();
        player.Name = textBox1.Text;

        switch (player.Name.ToUpper())
        {
            case "N/A": 
               Label_Question.Text = "Please set your name!"; 
               return;
            default: 
               Label_Question.Hide(); 
               break;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: changed the code to get rid of the pesky GOTO statement aswell.

Comment: I removed the goto (my bad, didn't ponder all that much about it, even though its' useless).